# Finding inverse of a function with domain R

Tags: functions

We have a function $G$ given by :

$\begin{aligned}G(x) = \begin{cases}0, & x<0\\
        \frac{x^2}{2}, & 0\leqslant  x < 1\\
        1, & x \geqslant 1\end{cases}\end{aligned}$

Find a function $\alpha$ with domain $\mathbb{R}$ such that $G(\alpha(t)) = t$ for $t \in (0,1/2)$.

So my approach was:
$\alpha(t) = G^{-1}(t)$

then I considered the interval $(0,1/2)$ and identified the inverse function for 
$G(t) = \frac{t^2}{2}$ which is $\pm \sqrt{2t}$.

However $G^{-1}(t) =\pm \sqrt{2t}$ cannot take negative values for $t$. since thesquareroot of a negative number is not defined. (let us ignore complex numbers).

hence the function $G^{-1}(t) = \alpha(t) = \pm \sqrt{2t}$ will have a domain of $\mathbb{R}_{\geqslant 0}$ ,i.e excluding negative numbers...

Can anyone help me here with inputs for the above question? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

We can define $\alpha$ as

$$\alpha(t)=\begin{cases} \sqrt{2t}& t \in (0,\frac12) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then for $t \in (0, \frac12),G(\alpha (t))=G(\sqrt{2t})=\frac{(\sqrt{2t})^2}{2}=t$

Alternatively, since the question is about finding an $\alpha$ that satisfies $G(\alpha(t))=t, t\in (0,0.5)$. you can also define $\alpha$ to be

$$\alpha(t)=\begin{cases} -\sqrt{2t}& t \in (0,\frac12) \\ \pi & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

or

$$\alpha(t)=\begin{cases} \sqrt{2t}& t \in (0,\frac12) \\ 1 & t \in [1/2,\infty) \\ 0 & (-\infty,0] \end{cases} \\ $$

Comment: In either case the answer is 't'. Thank you SiongthyeGoh!

Comment: A quick question: how does sqrt(2t) satisfy the domain R? I understand t can't be negative?

Comment: If $t \in (0, \frac12)$, I define it to be $\alpha(t)=\sqrt{2t}$, if it is some other real number, I define $\alpha(t)=0$, that handles every real number right?

Comment: in second case when alpha(t) = -sqrt(2t); why is it pi otherwise?

Comment: There are two conditions for the function $\alpha$ right?
1) Domain being $\mathbb{R}$.
2) $G(\alpha(t))=t$, for $t \in (0,1/2)$
There are no restrictions on the value of $\alpha$ for $t \notin (0,1/2)$, hence I can define it to be anything right?